# Do Elasticsearch CRUD need refresh?

Tags: elasticsearch, synchronization, refresh, real-time, crud

I need to sync a RDBS data with Elasticsearch. The common approach to achieve this is applying changes on the RDBS and then to use a message queue (or a table used to ETL) to apply same changes on ES.

The same Elasticsearch blog suggests to pop 1000 messages from the queue and push them in a bulk request with inserts, updates and deletes.

It’s known that ES is NEAR real-time and a refresh is needed before changes would be visible to search requests.

Given this fact the question is: Do **CRUD** operation with an **EXPLICIT ID** (GET, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) need a refresh if performed in row? In other words: are CRUDs in row REAL-TIME?

By reading few articles it looks like they don’t need a refresh and they are applied in real time, but I would like to get a confirm.

To be more clear: I **don’t** need to perform **search** requests (where refresh is needed to make changes visible), but just using explicit ID access. I **don’t mind** when these changes will become visible to searches.

If two CRUD requests are performed in row on ES:

1. INDEX document with id=1
2. UPDATE (or DELETE) document with id=1

Does the 2) need to wait a refresh to see 1)?

If yes I don’t find a way to achieve consistency between a RDBS and ES because same operations in row would end up with an updated (or deleted) document on the RDBS, but would fail on ES due to lack of refresh.

Comment: you are right you don't need a refresh. I have never experienced a delay and the docs also say it will not take more than a second to get indexed

Comment: The point is: is this reliable regardless of how quick the two CRUDs are sent in row? The 2) could happen just one millisecond after 1) and I need to be sure that 2) doesn’t end up failing. I can’t rely on a near real-time for this task, even if happens in less than a second. Those two CRUDs could be taken from the queue and get executed immediately in row and I wouldn’t have a control over delay between the two requests.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

You don't need a refresh. It will be consistent means operations are executed in order. ES makes sure always latest request succeeds. And it makes the changes persistent every `index/update/delete` request.

In case, there are two write requests received at different network partition for an ID and later one succeeds first, then earlier one will not be updated as consistency is achieved by versioning. Latest version data always succeeds.

Long answer:

You need to look at many concepts like `translog`, `fsync`, `consistency at ES, 'optimistic concurrency control', versioning, partitioning, availability`.

ES achieves consistency using versioning. So when you sent `index/update/delete` requests it does the following things at high level.

1. Writes it to translog
2. Makes it persistent - there is a default interval property. When that interval elapses or after every `index/delete/update` operation
3. Sends the request to the node
4. The node which received the request identifies the leader of the partition where the data belongs to.
5. Partition-leader-node writes the data and forwards to other replica-nodes where this partition should be replicated.
6. Once all are acknowledged, return the status to the client via the initial node-which-received-the-request.

There are many concepts/algorithms in this to make it powerful distributed system.

Comment: Thank you, now it’s pretty clear. I didn’t find anything on ES docs related to this, even if it should be explained clearly to users (or maybe if you have some docs reference it would be useful). As I just replied to @vigneshwar in the comment above I can’t have any control over the delay between 1) and 2) requests and they could happen immediately in row. Can I trust this ES “safe consistency” behavior you showed regardless the delay between the two request?

Comment: Yes, you can trust ES. Means latest request always succeeds.

Comment: Awesome! Regarding my main task: does requests order get preserved within the same bulk request for the same document ID and same target index? I read about this being valid within the same bulk requests, but not across different bulk requests for the same ID and index

Comment: You can assume that `same index, same id` requests will be in order.

Comment: I’m in doubt about this. You wrote about two different network requests with the same document ID which reach ES. How can ES detect which request should have been processed before if no explicit version is provided? Let’s suppose to have 2 different bulk requests A and B which reach ES a bit delayed: A update the “foo”: “bar” and B “foo”: “baz”. What would happen if the sending order was A, B but B reach ES first? How can ES figure out to not perform A if no versions are provided in A and B?

Comment: If no explicit version are provided in both two bulk requests couldn’t this end up with a wrong state as A reaches ES after a while and updates the state to “foo”: “bar”? Or if B reaches ES first, but while the B update is being performed then A reaches ES and updates the state with “foo”: “bar” successfully. This could ends up with a version conflict on B

Comment: @Siph Version is maintained internally. You don't need to provide explicit. In that case B will be updated. A will not be performed.