# How update works in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, kibana

I'm facing an optimization problem on update: I need to understand how the Elasticsearch update mechanics work with their documents in a low level view.

Is it true that Elasticsearch marks as deleted the previous record, without physically deleting it, and rewrites it to a new record, wasting more space than necessary?

Comment: could you approve the below answer if it was helpful? Else let us know what is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ES uses Lucene under the hood.

So update process is as follows high level

1. Insert operation
2. Marked older one for deletion - soft deletion
3. When Lucene merges segments. It actually deletes the marked documents i.e tombstones.

At high level, how does [crud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483673/do-elasticsearch-crud-need-refresh/62487252?r=SearchResults#62487252) work in ES.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more info to @Gibbs answer, and specific to optimization:

You can utilize the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) **with partial doc(send only the field which are changed)** to save the n/w bandwidth, however under the hood it will be the complete rewrite of existing doc but if you have large docs then you would save a lot of time in n/w transfer.